# get bean in struts

Tags: jsp, struts, jstl

I am new to struts and I saw below code in my current project

```
<logic:equal name="USER" property="readOnlyRole"  value="false" >
```

is **USER** in `name="USER"` a bean object? above code means **`USER.isReadOnlyRole`** right?

I want to implement a **OR** condition here, how would I do that for above condition. I know I can use `jstl choose` tag. Is following code correct replacement of above?

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${USER.isReadOnlyRole == 'false'}">
       False
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${USER.isReadOnlyRole == 'true'}">
        True
    </c:when>

</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Sandy,

```
 <logic:equal name="USER" property="readOnlyRole"  value="false" >
```

You are right, above code checks for the equality of ***value of readOnlyRole property of USER bean*** with ***false***.

However there is small change in your second code using c tag. Just replace User.isReadOnlyRole with User.readOnlyRole. It should be `<BEAN NAME>.<PROPERTY NAME>`. You can also use *eq* for checking equality, *ne* for not equal, etc. (You can use == as well.)

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${USER.readOnlyRole eq false}">
       False
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${USER.readOnlyRole eq true}">
        True
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Hope it helps.